# gdborig.exe has stopped working trying to attach to Javaw from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, gdb

I would like to use eclipse to debug the C code of a JNI aplication I am writing. I have followed some tutorial and done the following:

- Launch the Java program in debug mode
- Reach a breakpoint in Java code before calling loadLibrary()
- Run the "C/C++ attach to application" debug configuration in Eclipse by passing javaw.exe as a program to attach to

At this point I get an error window "gdborig.exe has stopped working" and the following output in the console:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later         <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
```

I am a bit stuck as I cannot see an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it as follows:
Debug Configurations>Select my configuration>Debug>"Select Other..." at the bottom to select "Use legacy Attach to process launcher
Then in Debugger, selected MinGW gdb

Comment: I am having the same problem, but I don't understand your directions.  After I get to debug configurations I see non of the rest that you have described.

Comment: is this why you downvoted? You obviously have a different version so try to look yourself how to select the legacy mode...